# create buttons into listbox using ObservableCollection in wp8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

In my windows phone application I want to add buttons dynamically When I click on `Add` button as you can see on the image:

[image]

And below is the code that I am using on the `Add` button.

xaml page code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="24,0,0,0">
            <TextBox x:Name="tb_groupname"
                 Height="90"
                 Background="White" 
                 Margin="0,0,125,517"

                 Foreground="Blue" TextChanged="tb_groupname_TextChanged" GotFocus="tb_groupname_GotFocus" LostFocus="tb_groupname_LostFocus"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_groupname"
                    Content="Add"
                    Background="AliceBlue"
                    Foreground="Blue"
                    FontSize="25"
                    Width="120"
                    Height="90"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_groupname_Click"></Button>
            <ListBox x:Name="lb_groupofcontacts" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,118,0,0">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Width="100" Height="100" Click="btn_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

xaml.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace GetContacts
{
    public partial class createGroups : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        string buttonName = "";
        public ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn;      
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        public createGroups()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_groupname_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (tb_groupname.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                groupbtn = new ObservableCollection<Group>()
                {
                    new Group {Name = tb_groupname.Text}
                };
                lb_groupofcontacts.DataContext = groupbtn;
            }
        }
        private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          // some code
        }

    }
}
```

And `Group` is my class below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    class Group
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Group()
        { 

        }
        public Group(Button btn)
        {
            Name = btn.Name;

        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error below at this line public `ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn;` and at this reference `groupbtn`

```
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<GetContacts.Group>' is less accessible than field
```

Kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new list every time and hence at a given time it will just has one button that you most recently add.

so instead of defining `List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>()` locally. So either make this collection member variable

**OR** use proper MVVM to do it correctly. (Still this is not the proper example of using MVVM but trying to make it as close as possible for your solution)
I would suggest you to define the properties like below (Implement INotifyPropertyChanged)

```
       public  ObservableCollection<string> Buttons{get;set;}
       public  string ButtonName{get;set;}
```

and bind your textbox and define ItemTemplate for your ListBox like:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tb_groupname" Text="{Binding ButtonName}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="lb_groupofcontacts" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" Margin="0,118,0,0">
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Button FontSize="25" Width="120" Height="90" Content="{Binding}"></Button>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

now just initialize you button collection in the initialize method

```
     public MainWindow()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        Buttons = ObservableCollection<string>();
        DataContext = this;
     }


private void btn_groupname_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ButtonName != string.Empty)
    {
            Buttons.Add(ButtonName);
           ButtonName = string.Empty;
    }            
}
```

Inconsistent accessibility error: Generally this happens because your field or class is private. You must change it to public

like `public class Group {}`

Comment: is it giving you some binding errors in output window?

Comment: did you mean this `public ObservableCollection<Group> groupbtn; `

Comment: no your class definition it should be `public class Group{}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55119/discussion-between-user88-and-nit).